# Unable to call a service of project from another computer

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

Created a project in xampp, created services using php, the services are working fine in local, Iam able to get the response and my computer is having static ip address. when im calling the service from another computer Im unable to get the response it is showing site cant be reached.

The System is having static ip address(http://27.xxx.xx.218/), i am calling the services from outside of the network.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Maybe this is issue with closed ports? And what is this static ip address you have? Are you trying to reach this service from within local network or outside of it? (please add this information in the question, not as a comment)

Comment: Ok, thanks! Another question - even though this IP is static - is it public? Did you register this at your internet provider? Are you able to reach your server from WITHIN your local network (using its local address), but not from the same machine? Can you provide this information again in the question AND try to read your question as if it was not yours, and provide any information that you feel might be missing, any details?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in the same network to access the other computer. Then just put in the local ip address of the other computer to access the web page. If not on the same network then you need to connect the two networks have a look at [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/627894/how-should-i-bridge-two-networks-given-each-network-has-its-own-subnet-dhcp-s).